# Concurrency not working in Azure table storage

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

While working with Azure Table Storage, I'm getting concurrency issues with multiple threads. Each thread is trying to update the same record (Partition key + Row key). In that case, my expectation is that if it is stale data, the library will automatically check the `etag` and throw an exception 412 Pre-Condition Failed. But, in my situation, it is always updating with last call.

It's worth noting that if I use `TableEntityOperation.Replace(entity)`, it does throw the 412 exception. It seems like `TableEntityOperation.InsertorMerge(entity)` doesn't check for concurrency.

Comment: Can you show your code here? Not enough detail for anyone to help.

Comment: Sure, I have added the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this behavior is because `TableEntityOperation.InsertorMerge(entity)` method, which is a wrapper over [`Insert Or Merge Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-or-merge-entity) REST API operation does not support optimistic concurrency. Only [`Merge Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/merge-entity) and [`Update Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/update-entity2) support optimistic concurrency.

From the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-or-merge-entity#remarks) (emphasis mine):

> The Insert Or Merge Entity operation uses the MERGE verb and must be
> called using the 2011-08-18 version or newer. **In addition, it does not
> use the If-Match header**. These attributes distinguish this operation
> from the Update Entity operation, though the request body is the same
> for both operations.

Comment: Just to add to it - you cannot check the Response for Status == 412, you have to catch the RequestFailedException... really bad SDK design if you ask me...